# Easy way to test network application

Tags: sip

I need to test my application. Its a VoIP but each time I need to keep someone on the other side of the call to test my application. Is there any service which allows us to test SIP or any network application easy way ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try [SIPp](http://sipp.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 2):

You could also try [sipsak](http://sipsak.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Implement a server using tested software locally and connect to it. Even better find server software that does very detailed logging.

Answer (score 0):

Out here we use wireshark traces for lab testing of POC ( proof of concepts ) applications . Just in case if that helps your case

ps: for deployed apps running at client environments use Network Test Factory , TCS offering .